# What is use of ServiceConnection

Tags: android

### I am trying to connect my LocalBinder from MyService.java class and it needed this code

```
private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

            MyLocalBinder binder = (MyLocalBinder)service;
            myService=binder.getService();
            isBound = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                isBound=false;
        }
    };
-
```

---

can you tell me what this code actually means and what is ServiceConnection and its actual uses.

Comment: It allows components (such as activities) to bind to the service, send requests, receive responses, and perform interprocess communication (IPC)

Comment: Why you want to connect to LocalBinder? I would like to listen what you wants to achieve rather than this, so i can help

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services